# Delete the final "s" of a word if the same word without the final "s" exists in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two array like this:

```
var tendances= ["noyades", "noyade", "décès", "accidentelles", "auteurs"];
var nb_tendances = [10, 6, 4, 3, 3];
```

The two array correspond to each other like this :

```
noyades = 10
noyade = 6
décès = 4
accidentelles = 3
auteurs = 3
```

What I want :

```
tendances = ["noyade", "décès", "accidentelles", "auteurs"];
nb_tendances = [16, 4, 3, 3];
```

So my question is: how can I accumulate the plural and singular forms of a word by ignoring the final 's' ? I would like to replace the words ending with an "s" only if the same word without the final "s" exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.forEach` and `Array.splice`

```js
var tendances= ["noyades", "noyade", "décès", "accidentelles", "auteurs"]
var nb_tendances = [10, 6, 4, 3, 3]


tendances.forEach(function(val, i) {
    let index = tendances.indexOf(val + 's')
    if(index === -1) return
    
    nb_tendances[index] += nb_tendances[i]
    tendances.splice(i, 1)
    nb_tendances.splice(i, 1)
})

console.log(tendances)
console.log(nb_tendances)
```